# awk float point representation

Tags: bash, shell, awk

Hey I am new to shell script and I am trying to write something involving float point calculation. I intended to use either bc or awk.

However, since I cannot find a way to tell bc do x^(1/3) correctly, I ended up with awk. I get everything done except for one problem: for doing division with awk, whenever my dividend is smaller than 1, say, 0.0064, awk seems to read it as 0. Therefore I got inf as the result. I am not sure where I did wrong.

Here is my code, I need to store the calculated value into variables, not necessarily to print them out.

And I am also curious about how are values treated by bc, awk or simple expres'' form? Are they read/stored as numerical value or strings?

In addition, just to use awk as a calculate, can I do x=$(echo "expression" | awk) or something similar, without using print expression in awk '{ }'?

```
#!/bin/bash


# molar concentration = 0.1 mM per nm^3
MOLAR=0.0001
NA=6.02*10^23
CONV=1*10^24

number_concentration=$(echo "scale=10;$MOLAR * $NA / ($CONV)" | bc)
echo $number_concentration

# determine box size
volume=$(awk 'BEGIN {print 1+$number_concentration}' /dev/null)
echo $volume

# length
a=$(echo awk 'BEGIN {$volume^(1/3)}' /dev/null)
```

Comment: That shell snippet doesn't work correctly since your variables aren't being used in the awk scripts at all. You have the scripts in single quotes so the shell isn't expanding your variable values. I would use awk's `-v` argument to pass the values in to awk.

Comment: I used the double quotes and it works! Thank you!

Comment: `0.0064` is smaller than `0`?

Comment: wrt `I used the double quotes and it works!` - that is a terrible idea as it leads to quoting and escaping hell in your awk scripts. Don't do that since it's completely unnecessary.

Comment: Hey Ed, can you elaborate more on your comments? Sorry I am very new to scripts so I don't really get what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `echo` and `awk` to do this.

```
#!/bin/bash


# molar concentration = 0.1 mM per nm^3
MOLAR=0.0001
NA=6.02*10^23
CONV=1*10^24

number_concentration=$(echo "$MOLAR $NA $CONV" | awk '{print $1*$2/$3}')
echo $number_concentration

# determine box size
volume=$(echo "$number_concentration" | awk '{print 1+$1}')
echo $volume

# length
a=$(echo $volume | awk '{print $1^(1/3)}')
echo $a
```

Comment: Thanks for the change! Can you explain why we need the print comment over there? Will awk just perform the arithmetic?

Comment: `awk` will print the value to stdout which is assigned to the variables, `volume, a` etc...

Comment: You need the print to get awk to print the result of the arithmetic out. Otherwise it doesn't go anywhere and your assignment won't see it.

Answer (score 3):

I'd write that like this, with a single call to awk:

```
MOLAR="0.0001"
NA="6.02*10^23"
CONV="1*10^24"

read concentration volume length < <(
    awk "BEGIN {
        molar=$MOLAR; na=$NA; conv=$CONV
        conc = molar * na / conv
        vol = 1 + conc
        len = vol ^ (1/3)
        printf \"%.8f %.8f %.8f\\n\", conc, vol, len
    }"
)

printf "%s\n" $concentration $volume $length
```

```
0.00006020
1.00006020
1.00002007
```

Note that you may have issues with loss of precision of floating point numbers:

```
% awk "BEGIN {print $MOLAR, $NA, $CONV}"
0.0001 601999999999999928696832 999999999999999983222784
```

---

If the bash vars can be expressed in "scientific notation", then we're OK:

```
MOLAR="0.0001"
NA="6.02e23"
CONV="1e24"

awk  -v molar="$MOLAR" -v na="$NA" -v conv="$CONV" 'BEGIN {
    conc = molar * na / conv
    vol = 1 + conc
    len = vol ^ (1/3)
    printf "%.8f %.8f %.8f\n", conc, vol, len
}'
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! Can you explain also what awk (commmand) will  return?  A set of values or because of the read command you can use awk this way?

Comment: The read command is what takes the three values that awk prints out (via the `printf` line) and sets them into the shell variables.

Comment: `NA` will be truncated to `6.02` and `CONV` to `1`. Is that really what's desired?

Comment: Because for NA you're taking a numeric-string of "6.02*10^23" and then performing an arithmetic operation on it which tells awk to convert it to a number, and the process awk uses to do that is to cut off everything after the last number in the numeric-string, i.e. everything from the '*' on, so it ends up with just the leading "6.02"

Comment: Yes, you're right. I'll fix. Thanks Ed, I appreciate your review.

Comment: To avoid having to escape various other chars (double quotes, backslashes, and $ signs at least), I wouldn't use double quotes around the whole script, IMHO localizing the transitions to `awk 'BEGIN { molar='"$MOLAR"'; na=...` is much preferable if you really want to have some shell variables expand inline within the awk script.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just do it all in awk?

```
awk 'BEGIN {
    molar = 0.0001
    na    = 6.02   * 10 ^ 23
    conv  = 1      * 10 ^ 24

    number_concentration = molar * na / conv
    volume = 1 + number_concentration
    a = volume ^ (1/3)

    print number_concentration, volume, a
}'  
6.02e-05 1.00006 1.00002
```

Use `printf` instead of `print` if you need different output formatting.

If you NEED to define your variables in the shell before your awk script for some reason:

```
MOLAR="0.0001"
NA="6.02*10^23"
CONV="1*10^24"

awk 'BEGIN {
    molar = '"$MOLAR"'
    na    = '"$NA"'
    conv  = '"$CONV"'

    number_concentration = molar * na / conv
    volume = 1 + number_concentration
    a = volume ^ (1/3)

    print number_concentration, volume, a
}'
6.02e-05 1.00006 1.00002
```

or don't even use awk variables for the initial values:

```
MOLAR="0.0001"
NA="6.02*10^23"
CONV="1*10^24"

awk 'BEGIN {
    number_concentration = ('"$MOLAR"') * ('"$NA"') / ('"$CONV"')
    volume = 1 + number_concentration
    a = volume ^ (1/3)

    print number_concentration, volume, a
}'   
6.02e-05 1.00006 1.00002
```

Note that the above is NOT the normal way to access the value of shell variables in an awk script, normally you'd pass their value in using `awk -v awkvar="$shellvar" ...`, but in this case we need the actual text expansion of the shell variables to take place in-line in the awk script before it gets interpreted by awk, whereas normally that behavior would be undesirable due to potential breakage as the shell variables could expand to something that causes an awk syntax error or other undesirable behavior.

So, only do this for a number (a numeric expression may be the only use for this):

```
awk 'BEGIN{awkvar='"$shellvar"'} {script}'
```

or this for a string (not sure this is actually ever necessary):

```
awk 'BEGIN{awkvar="'"$shellvar"'"} {script}'
```

in preference to this:

```
awk -v awkvar="$shellvar" '{script}'
```

when you have full control over the contents of shellvar, know the caveats you are dealing with, and NEED shellvar to be expanded in-place before awk interprets the script.